# new to programming - error reached end of file while parsing when running code in repl.it/CD18/4

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, java.util.scanner, indexof

I'm new to programming and trying to write a script that outputs a line containing ***pangram*** if the input **s** is a pangram, or otherwise ***not pangram***. When I compile the script I get an error *"reached end of file while parsing."*  I believe I have balanced parenthesis. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean flag = false;
        Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = key.nextLine();
        String upperCaseStr = s.toUpperCase();

        for(char alphabet = 'A'; alphabet <='Z'; alphabet++) {
            if(upperCaseStr.indexOf(alphabet)==-1){
                flag=true;
                break;
            }  
        }
        if (flag){
            System.out.print("not ");
        }
        System.out.println("pangram");
    }
}
```

Comment: no Idea what a pangram is, but what error message do you exactly get, and what line in your code does it point to?

Comment: This class should be compiling without problem. How do you compile it? How is the .java file named?

Comment: also a good thing to check: did you save the file before trying to compile?

Comment: A `pangram` is a word or sentence that contains all the characters of the Alphabet

Comment: Works fine for me when I run it

Comment: Hang on, that error only appears to happen if you try and type in again, you do know this will only run once right? Did you want to allow multiple inputs?

Comment: @Draken You are correct! Stupid mistake. I guess it's the late hour...

Comment: Glad I could help, feel free to mark my answer as correct :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this if you want to keep doing multiple inputs:

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean continue = true;
        while (continue){
            boolean flag = false;
            Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
            String s = key.nextLine();
            String upperCaseStr = s.toUpperCase();
            //if (upperCaseStr.trim() == "QUIT"){
            //    continue = false;
            //} -> don't compare Object's values by their references
            continue = "QUIT".equals(s.toUpperCase());
            for(char alphabet = 'A'; alphabet <= 'Z'; alphabet++) {
                if(upperCaseStr.indexOf(alphabet)==-1){
                    flag=true;
                    break;
                }  
            }
            if (flag){
                System.out.print(s + " is not a pangram");
            }
            else
                System.out.println(s + " is a pangram");
        }
    }
}
```

Though you need to do something to break out the while loop, like look for if the user types quit or something, but should help

[Edit] Added quit clause

Comment: Thanks @Stultuske, was having a moment trying to fix that bit :)

Comment: better yet, read the new value at the end of the while loop.
unless you want people to find out whether or not "quit" is a pangram

Comment: You never know, it could be ;)